# How to get the date portion only of a cell value to be used in a file name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this line of code:

```
var blob = response.getBlob().setName(ss.getRange('C3').getValue() +  ' - ' + sheet.getName() + ' - ' + ss.getRange('C7').getValue() + '.pdf');
```

. . . and the value in C7 is a date:

[image]

This is the result that shows up as the file name, but I only want to see the date portion.
[image]

I tried formatting the date before I send it in; and I tried formatting it within the var blob line . . .

```
var myDate = ss.getRange('C7').getValue().setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

var blob = response.getBlob().setName(ss.getRange('C3').getValue() +  ' - ' + sheet.getName() + ' - ' + myDate + '.pdf');
```

. . .but I get this error:
[image]

Can someone show me the correct way to get the date portion only from the value in cell C7? Ideally, I would like the file name to read like this:   `NAME - Timesheet - 07/06/2020`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just the Date

```
var dts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(ss.getRange('C7').getValue()),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd,yyyy");
var blob = response.getBlob().setName(ss.getRange('C3').getValue() +  ' - ' + sheet.getName() + ' - ' + dts + '.pdf');
```

[Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

[FormatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

[Date Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: It comes out exactly the same. I did a Logger.log and the value includes the time. I did change this in the last line " + ss.getRange('C7').getValue()" to " + dts", but no difference.

Comment: I can post the file if that helps.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!